# sort array by keys and reverse the result

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a array like this:

```
$array = array(
   [1]=>'something',
   [0.2]=>'something',
   [0.1]=>'something',
   [0.3]=>'something',
   [0.10]=>'something'
);
```

Now i like to sort this array by key, so for that i am using this code:

```
uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');
```

The above code works fine, but the only problem is that i want to reverse the result.
For this purpose i used `krsort` , `array_reverse` , `rsort` after `uksort`, but all of them change `uksort`'s result.

So have can i sort this array by key in natural order and reverse the result?

What i want should be like :

```
$array = array(
   [1]=>'something',
   [0.10]=>'something',
   [0.3]=>'something',
   [0.2]=>'something',
   [0.1]=>'something'
);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
uksort($array, create_function('$a,$b', 'return -strnatcasecmp($a,$b);'));
```

Since you already use a variant of uksort (user-function defined sort), this version just reverses the order by inverting the result of the comparison function. I think it should work for you.

Alternatively try this:

```
uksort($array, 'strnatcasecmp');
$array = array_reverse($array, true);
```

Note the `true` parameter, that preserves your keys.

**Update** for modern PHP versions, since `create_function` is deprecated:

```
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) { return -strnatcasecmp($a, $b); });
```

**Update** for PHP 7.4 with new syntax (not released as of writing):

```
uksort($array, fn($a, $b) => -strnatcasecmp($a, $b));
```

Answer (score 1):

For PHP 4+, you can use [krsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php):

```
krsort($array, SORT_NATURAL | SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Looks simpler to me, and it works the same as `strnatcasecmp()`. If you don't want it to be case sensitive, get rid of the `SORT_FLAG_CASE` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php programmer, but according to

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

you should be able to write your own call back function for the comparison and then sort them anyway you want to.

Answer (score 0):

`asort()` will sort by the key, `arsort()` will sort by the key and reverse the order.